# how to use the show function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Jquery and go through some tutorials with w3.

I cant work out why my code wont work for the 'show' function the opposite to hide.
this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).show();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

<style>

p { 
    visibility: hidden;
}

</style>



</body>
</html>
```

it seems obvious but as the page loads all the `<p>` elements are not visible due to the styling but then i thought on click they should show? they don't. is the style too overpowering? if so how do you stop this? or i have made a simple error elsewhere.

thanks

Comment: How would a user click on a `p` element that is not visible?

Comment: See another w3 demo of how to show instead here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

**First**, from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block"),
>   except that the display property is restored to whatever it was
>   initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden
>   and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

The function you are calling will modify the `display` of the elements but not the `visibility` (which you have set to hidden).

To modify the visibility you would need to do so explicitly.

```
$(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
```

**Second**, even though an invisible element will take up space on the page, you can't click on something that isn't visible. It just won't fire the click event.

You can work around this by wrapping each paragraph in another element and putting the event listener on that.

```js
 $("div").click(function() {
   $(this).find('p').css('visibility', 'visible');
 });
```

```css
p {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Click me away!</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Click me too!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

`$(this).show()` won't change the visibility css property. Try: `$(this).css("visibility", "visible");`

Comment: Downvoted because even though your solution is correct, it will not solve his problem. You failed to point out that the `p` cannot be clicked on because it's not visible to be clicked on.

Answer (score -2):

How would you click on p element?

I think you should make a button element and on clicking that try to show the p element. 
       I think it would be helpful :)

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Hey Stephan, can you check now my answer. Is that work for you?

Answer (score -2):

Just use below Code that will work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").css("visibility", "visible");
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button>click on me.</button>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

<style>

p { 
visibility: hidden;
 }

</style>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Obese,  Hope it will work for you. have a nice day